# .fillna breaking .dt.normalize()

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to clean up some data, by formatting my floats to show no decimal points and my date/time to only show date. After this, I want to fill in my NaNs with an empty string, but when I do that, my date goes back to showing both date/time. Any idea why? Or how to fix it.

This is before I run the fillna() method with a picture of what my data looks like:

```
#Creating DataFrame from path variable
daily_production_df = pd.read_excel(path)

#Reformated Data series to only include date (excluded time)
daily_production_df['Date'] = daily_production_df['Date'].dt.normalize()

pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.0f}'.format
#daily_production_df = daily_production_df.fillna('')

#Called only the 16 rows that have data, including the columns/header
daily_production_df.head(16)
```

[code with NaNs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNzlB.png)

This is when I run the fillna() method:

```
daily_production_df = pd.read_excel(path)

#Reformated Data series to only include date (excluded time)
daily_production_df['Date'] = daily_production_df['Date'].dt.normalize()

pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.0f}'.format
daily_production_df = daily_production_df.fillna('')

#Called only the 16 rows that have data, including the columns/header
daily_production_df.head(16)
```

[date_time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/537ip.png)

Comment: There's generally a difference between the value pandas displays based on formatting rules and the underlying data that represents that cell. A `datetime64ns` value always has seconds, ms, ns, etc. just pandas doesn't unecessarily display them when _all_ of the values in a column have 0 sec, 0 ms, 0ns, .... However when you `.fillna('')` you upcast the column to object, so my guess is pandas then displays exactly what that value is (b/c the column is `object` dtype) instead of using rules for `datetime64ns` to intelligently display the data.

Answer (score 0):

Using `normalize()` does not change the dtype of the column, pandas just stop displaying the time portion when print because they share the same time portion.

I would recommend the correct solution which is convert the column to actual `datetime.date` instead of using `normalize()`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date
```

Comment: in my code I used `pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`. Forgot to put that in the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I can't normalize() after fillna() because fillna() converts every data type to object and i can only use dt.normalizer() in datetime types. However! I did substitute my normalize() code with your datetime.date converter and I like that better, since I don't need time at all. Thank you so much!

Comment: yeah I probably should remove that part in my answer since it is not optimal anyway